# flutter run failed: A problem occurred configuring project ':shared_preferences'

Tags: gradle, dart, flutter, sharedpreferences

I am Using flutter 1.2 and my project runs successfully before I add shared_preferences package to it.I am using  `shared_preferences: ^0.5.1+2.` after I add it, `flutter run` command creates this error:

> - Error running Gradle: ProcessException: Process "/home//Desktop/projects/fycx/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:
>     Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use
>     --status for details
>
> > Configure project :shared_preferences
>
> Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run
>   with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':shared_preferences'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':shared_preferences:classpath'.
>   >     Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find gradle-core.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/3.1.2/gradle-core-3.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.1.0-alpha01).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.1.0-alpha01/bundletool-0.1.0-alpha01.jar
>   >     Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.1.2/builder-3.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/3.1.2/gradle-api-3.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find compilerCommon.jar (com.android.databinding:compilerCommon:3.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/compilerCommon/3.1.2/compilerCommon-3.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/26.1.2/manifest-merger-26.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find sdk-common.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.1.2/sdk-common-26.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find sdklib.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/26.1.2/sdklib-26.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find repository.jar (com.android.tools:repository:26.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/repository/26.1.2/repository-26.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find builder-test-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:3.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/3.1.2/builder-test-api-3.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find ddmlib.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/26.1.2/ddmlib-26.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find tracker.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/tracker/26.1.2/tracker-26.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find shared.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/26.1.2/shared-26.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find layoutlib-api.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:26.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/26.1.2/layoutlib-api-26.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find dvlib.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:26.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/26.1.2/dvlib-26.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find common.jar (com.android.tools:common:26.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/common/26.1.2/common-26.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.1.0).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.1.0/aapt2-proto-0.1.0.jar
>   >     Could not find protos.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/26.1.2/protos-26.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find builder-model.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/3.1.2/builder-model-3.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find apksig.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:3.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/3.1.2/apksig-3.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find baseLibrary.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.1.2/baseLibrary-3.1.2.jar
>   >     Could not find annotations.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:26.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/26.1.2/annotations-26.1.2.jar
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 51s   Command:
>   /home/Desktop/projects/fycx/android/gradlew app:properties
>
> Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are missing libraries which are supported by [dl.google.com](http://dl.google.com) which is likely to be prohibited on your location, to test whether it is banned or not try downloading flutter source from browser using the [official link](https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/windows/flutter_windows_v1.2.1-stable.zip) and see if it will give you an `Access denied` or open a download dialog. In the case of blockade turning the VPN on and running the project using `flutter run` will solve your problem.

Comment: I have used a vpn, and I can open that link, still it gives me the same error

Comment: some VPNs doesn't work system-wide like psiphon, which VPN are you using ?

Comment: I am using CiscoAnyConnect

Comment: I am using ubuntu OS, maybe this has something to do

Comment: honestly I don't know about its mechanism, but I know `Hotspot Shield` will solve it, I am not affiliated with them nor have any connections whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

I got result in just deleting android/.gradle file and run the app again. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install NDK first. After installing NDK, I can solve the problem by syncing again

Answer (score 0):

I have this error in 2.0.15 version too! but I have tried & I get this point that this error is not in this version :
2.0.13

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

use shared preferences version 0.5.6 instead of 0.5.6+1
it will work for this error